# good Wordpress theme for blogged book?

Tags: fiction, software, tools, book, blog

Leaving aside whether I *ought* to blog my book or not, I am doing just that. Each blog post will be a section, multiple sections will be a chapter, etc.

Currently I'm looking for a good wordpress theme for it. Doesn't have to be free, but shouldn't be more than $50 or so.

Should be elegant, simple, responsive, and a good fit for someone who wants to visit my site to read the book so far. Shouldn't be graphics heavy, as the point is the literary experience. A light off white theme may make some sense.

However, I've looked around on Google and on Wordpress.com itself and most of the themes I have found have been graphic image heavy. I'd like the experience of going to my new site to be somewhat like reading a book.

Also, when I search for themes related to authors or writers (or writing) I get themes useful for showcasing the author themselves, not their work. Again, lots of graphics.

So that's what I need help finding - a great wordpress theme for me to upload my writing to, section by section, so that others can come and read it as it gels.

Comment: I love [Qwerty](http://sevenbold.com/wordpress/qwerty/).

Comment: I'm really divided whether this question is on or off-topic. The help center mentions we accept questions about blogging, writing tools and ways to present your work, but the question still does not *feel* like it's related to writing.

Comment: A theme with JavaScript allowing for arrow key control to turn the pages would be nice. Have you looked into static site generators?

Comment: It is worth noting that with a $50 budget, you could probably hire a designer who was willing to put together a custom template to your specifications.  Look at one of the online marketplaces like freelancer.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress themes are evolving to reflect modern internet usage, which means website navigation that worked for *desktops* is being replaced with conventions more suitable for *cell phones*. The old functions are still available, but WP is becoming less "blog" and more "e-reader" with every update.

Most paid themes will feature a flexible layout that adjusts your content to fit a cell phone, but you could focus your search to mobile themes, and at the very least you should test the themes on a mobile device because the way the internet is headed the vast majority of new readers will discover you through social media or search engine, and these are already dominated by mobile devices.

Use **Pages** (not Posts) to publish sections and chapters that should be read in a specific order. *Posts* are for content that will be searched and re-sorted by the viewer using category, date, or tag words.

Pages can have sub-menu pages. A "book" might be a top-level page with "sections" and "chapters" as parented sub-menu pages. WP will create the sub-menu automatically, but you can also create a *Menu* that features or hides this structure.

Longer Pages can be presented as shorter book-like pages with a *nextpage* tag (WP calls it "pagination"), and your WordPress theme will handle the navigation.

Use **Posts** for related articles, worldbuilding content, in-store appearances, personal updates, etc. Anything that supports the book that isn't part of the text should be a Post. The simplest organization is to have a single Category named "blog" and put all Posts in there until there is a *need* to separate this content into definitive categories. Best usage is to have as few categories as possible so readers will be exposed to crossover content.

I keep reading criticisms that author/book websites are not updated enough. The blog area of your website is actually a *honeypot* to bring search engines and new readers to your book. Rather than silo information into well-separated Categories, you want to have a blog area that crosses many topics related to your book.

Use **Tags**, not Categories, to sort this information by topic. Your Tags should follow search engine conventions. Pick words that are *commonly used* over esoteric words specific to your book. Presumably the esoteric words will already be present throughout the text so, for example if you have a blog post with some worldbuilding content about your alien race called the *B'nyeagth*, resist the urge to tag it "B'nyeagth" because no one will discover your book by accidentally typing that word into a search engine. Use descriptions like "alien, planet, worldbuilding" – these words might not actually appear in the content of the post.

If you don't like graphics don't use graphics, but do create a **home page** to serve as the dust jacket of your book. Many trendy themes now have a fancy scroll presentation with testimonials and featured content. This fancy presentation only appears on the home page (or at the top of the latest Posts), and this is the one good place for graphics, your "writer's promise" to the reader, etc.

The rest is about tweaking the cosmetic choices of the theme. Don't use a sidebar at least not on your Pages, and find a theme that has a "full-width" template.

**TL;DR:**
[I paid for this theme because it unlocked full-width templates](https://catchthemes.com/demo/fotografie/templates/full-content-width-page/) that look good for reading.